# Box with two form options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that displays a box that has two options, one is "accepted" and the other "not accept". It turns out that when the user uses to send the email, he can send it with the button marked "not accept". Is there any way that I can make it validate?

HTML

```
                <div class="form">
                    <h4>Valor do consórcio: <span class="slider-value quote-form-element" data-name="Valor | Automóvel" data-slider-id="consorcio-auto">R$ <span></span></span></h4>
                    <div class="slider" data-slider-min="20000" data-slider-max="100000" data-slider-start="23192" data-slider-step="1000" data-slider-id="consorcio-auto"></div>

                    <h4>Seus dados:</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome..." class="quote-form-element" />
                    <input type="text" name="Cidade" placeholder="Cidade/UF..." class="quote-form-element quote-form-client-email last" />                           
                    <input type="text" name="Número de Telefone" placeholder="Telefone..." class="quote-form-element telefone" />
                    <input type="text" name="Endereço de Email" placeholder="E-mail..." class="quote-form-element quote-form-client-email last contact_email" />

                    <h4>Política de Privacidade</h4>
                    <div class="checkbox quote-form-element" data-checked="yes" data-name="Política de Privacidade">

                        <span class="checkbox-status"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
                        <span class="checkbox-values">


                            <span class="checkbox-value-checked" style="font-size: 12px">Li e aceito a politica de privacidade</span>
                            <span class="checkbox-value-unchecked">Não aceito</span> 
                        </span>

                    </div>

                    <button class="button button-navy-blue send-quote" type="button">Simular meu consórcio <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></button>



                    <div class="quote-form-thanks">

                        <div class="quote-form-thanks-content">

                                Obrigado pelo seu interesse, retornaremos em breve ;). 
                                <span class="quote-form-thanks-close">Fechar</span>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.send-quote').click(function () {

    var quoteForm = $(this).parent();
    var quoteFormParent = quoteForm.parent().parent();

    var insuranceType = quoteFormParent.data('quote-form-for');
    var fields = {};
    var fieldID = 0;

    var fieldName = '';
    var fieldValue = '';

    var clientName = '';
    var clientEmail = '';

    var errorFound = false;

    quoteForm.find('.quote-form-element').each(function (fieldID) {

        fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
        if (typeof fieldName == 'undefined' || fieldName === false) {

            fieldName = $(this).data('name');
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('checkbox')) {

            fieldValue = $(this).data('checked') == 'yes' ? $(this).children('.checkbox-values').children('.checkbox-value-checked').text() : $(this).children('.checkbox-values').children('.checkbox-value-unchecked').text();
        }

        else {

            fieldValue = $(this).is('input') || $(this).is('select') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
            if (($(this).is('input') && fieldValue == '') || ($(this).is('select') && fieldValue == '-')) {

                errorFound = true;
                $(this).addClass('error');
            }

            else {

                $(this).removeClass('error');
            }
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('quote-form-client-name')) clientName = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).hasClass('quote-form-client-email')) clientEmail = $(this).val();

        fields[fieldID] = { 'name': fieldName, 'value': fieldValue };
        fieldID++;

    });

    if (errorFound == false) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '_assets/submit.php',
            data: { 'send': 'quote-form', 'values': fields, 'clientName': clientName, 'clientEmail': clientEmail },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (output) {

                quoteForm.children('.quote-form-thanks').fadeIn(300);
            }

        });
    }

});
```

[page](http://consorciomenegalli.com.br/teste/) that displays the contents in the "Simulation".

Comment: i'm not sure if I understood. What do you want to validate exactly?

Comment: when the user select "not accept", the form can not be sent

Answer (score 0):

So you need to check if "no accept" is `checked` or not using radio inputs.

```js
$('.send-quote').click(function() {
  if ($('[name=terms]:checked').val() === 'no') {
    console.log('got an error');
  } else {
    console.log('all good');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="terms" value="yes" checked></input>
<label for="terms">Do accept terms</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="terms" value="no"></input>
<label for="terms">Don't accept terms</label>
<br>
<button type="button" class="send-quote">Send Quote</button>
```